# Squished axis when using ggplotly() with geom_sf()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, spatial, r-sf

I am trying to use `ggplotly()` to turn a `ggplot` object into a `plotly` object. This works fine when building the `ggplot` with tidied data from an `sp` object. However, plotting with `geom_sf()` squishes the y-axis to a fraction of the plot height. (See last image below.)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(plotly)
library(broom)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
```

#### Works fine when converting from sp object

```
nc_sp <- as_Spatial(nc$geometry)
nc_sp_df <- tidy(nc_sp)
p_sp <- ggplot(nc_sp_df) + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))

p_sp
```

[image: ggplot_sp]

```
ggplotly(p_sp)
```

[image: plotly_sp]

#### Something strange happens with sf objects

```
p_sf <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf()
p_sf
```

[image: ggplot_sf]

```
ggplotly(p_sf)
```

[image: plotly_sf]

**Session info**

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
[4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2       broom_0.4.1        plotly_4.7.1       sf_0.5-5          
[5] ggplot2_2.2.1.9000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not sf vs. sp, but rather how plotly handles a different coordinate system, i.e. from coord_map() or from coord_sf().
There are some issues that have been raised in the repository: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/499

If you install the development version of plotly: devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly'), the problem is solved.

```
devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly')
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
p_sf <- ggplot(nc) + geom_sf()
```

Set width and height arguments to avoid excess space

```
ggplotly(p_sf, width = 10, height = 3)
```

[image]

also see this blog post by the plotly developer on using ggplotly with geom_sf(): https://www.r-bloggers.com/learning-from-and-improving-upon-ggplotly-conversions/